# Floating with Masonry

Tags: css, masonry

I'm using Masonry to build up my portfoliowebsite. I build up my site in 3 columns.
But I noticed that if I float Left, only the upper right column will behave like I want to (like Masonry). If I float Right, only the upper left column will behave like I want to. 
Is there anyone who knows to solve this and can make my other two columns behave the same way?
Here is the CSS, where I think the problem is: 
    `.grid-item{width: 33%;}
    .grid-item--width2{width: 33%;}
    .grid-item--width3{width: 33%;}

```
*{box-sizing:border-box;}

.grid:after {
  content: '';
  clear: both;
}

.grid-item {
  width: 33%;
  float: left;
  border: 5px solid #FFFFFF;
}

.grid-sizer,
.grid-item {
  width: 33%;`
```

Comment: Floating can't achieve a Masonry effect that's why Masonry exists

Comment: If I leave away the float: left; , everything just stacks under each other..?

Comment: Yeah....that's why Masonry.js is needed....floating can't do Masonry...that's my point.